# Difference between processor affinity and I/O affinity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am preparing for a certification and trying to know the difference between processor affinity and I/O affinity. Would be thankful if someone could explain that to me in simple words.. Tried to learn about it on MS links, but got confused. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well I am no DBA but as far I understand, SQL Server runs on multiple thread (spawns multiple thread for serving request) being a multi threaded application.

You can specify/Map a particular thread(s) to work on specific CPU(s) (since high end server machines will run on 16 or more CPU). that is known as `Processor Affinity`.

Whereas, The `affinity I/O mask` or `I/O Affinity` option binds SQL Server disk I/O to a specified subset of CPU(s)

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189629.aspx), specific excerpt

> To carry out multitasking, Microsoft Windows 2000 and Windows Server
>   2003 sometimes move process threads among different processors.
>   Although efficient from an operating system point of view, this
>   activity can reduce Microsoft SQL Server performance under heavy
>   system loads, as each processor cache is repeatedly reloaded with
>   data. Assigning processors to specific threads can improve performance
>   under these conditions by eliminating processor reloads; such an
>   association between a thread and a processor is called **processor**
>   **affinity**.
>
> SQL Server supports processor affinity by means of two affinity mask
>   options: affinity mask (also known as **CPU affinity** mask) and
>   **affinity I/O mask**

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helped.. but is there any difference between these two??

Comment: I wouldn't differentiate between them. processor affinity is the main feature which is supported by CPU and I/O affinity mask.

Comment: Old question, but I'm always astounded at what gets left out.  Of course there is a difference between the two.  The affinity mask refers to CPU resources and the affinity IO mask refers to storage resources.  If you have an abundance of processing power but a shortage of disk space use your judgment to set IO affinity.  If it's the other way around (the usual case) set processor affinity